# UIButton displaying a square

Tags: objective-c

Here is my code to draw my square in my class shape.h (Subclass UIView)

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
        //Square

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,
                                 [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
 CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(20,20,80,80);
CGContextAddRect(context, rectangle);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

What i need help with is taking my code and implementing it into a button in my ViewController(h). Saying that whenever i touch the button i would like my square to appear. Im not sure if i'm explaining my self correctly, correct me if im wrong.

Comment: What is the problem you have faced with this code?

Comment: There is no problem with the code. im just confused on how to make a UIButton display my square instead of it just being there when i run the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it another way:

This is you IBAction that is called, when the button is pressed:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
 UIView *square = [[UIView alloc] init];
 square.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 80, 80);
 square.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
 [self.view addSubview:square];
}
```

This is the IBAction for a circle:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
    {
     UIView *circle = [[UIView alloc] init];
     circle.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 80, 80);
     circle.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
     circle.layer.cornerRadius = circle.frame.size.height/2;
     [self.view circle];
    }
```

Is that what you wanted? You don't need an extra subclass of UIView for this.

To connect the IBAction to the UIButton, right click in interface builder from the button to this method in code or like this:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

If you like to draw something more complex (like a triangle) you can subclass UIView. The Code above was for some really easy things. Here is some sample code for a triangle but I think you get the point:

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "triangle.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
    [button setTitle:@"Press me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    triangle *view = [[triangle alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, 200, 200)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
}

@end
```

triangle.m:

```
#import "triangle.h"

@implementation triangle

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
    CGContextMoveToPoint   (ctx, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));  // top left
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));  // mid right
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));  // bottom left
    CGContextClosePath(ctx);

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 100/255.f, 100/255.f, 100/255.f, 1);
    CGContextFillPath(ctx);
}

@end
```

Comment: Yes, that exactly what i wanted. Perhaps if i also want to add a circle would it be somewhat the same thing?

Comment: The easiest way to do this is by adding this line before adding the subview:

    square.layer.cornerRadius = square.frame.size.height/2;

Comment: And to remove the square view write [square removeFromSuperView];

Comment: You are welcome. As Abhilash said, the removeFromSuperView is for removing it from the screen. To do this it would be better to create a property for the UIView, so that you can call this method in other functions.

Comment: Guys any links to see the functions to make other shapes, im trying to add a triangle the same way.